# How to create ethreum wallet using WEB3j

Tags: web3j

I want to create my own Ethereum wallet,how can I do that and is it necessary to run GETH or similar to use wallet.It will be helpful if any good reference can be provided as I am very much new to it

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Ismael but my question is different its not only about creating account but also regarding client application GETH